# Storing a variable in project

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking at a simple wpf c# project to calculate an employee tax payment for a UK company. To do this I will need to store the UK tax allowances that are only updated infrequently. These values are shall we say 10000 and 45000 ( these are not the actual numbers I Know), but they may need to be updated in the future. 
I plan to store the app on a central network.

I have considered using resources to store these values but that will take the ability of the user to update these values away, which I do not want to do.

I have looked at isolated storage [like here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28179/Use-of-Isolated-Storage-A-Simple-Demo) but I think then different users could change their tax limits when really I need each allowance to be stored and updated by which ever user does the update.

Everything I have read about app.config file suggests that is not the right place either for such a variable.

So what should I do to store this data? I guess I could put down a Txt or XML file, which is fine in this case, but does not strike as a secure option and linking to SQL db seem over the top

What is the best practice in this case pls?

Thank you

Comment: How many entries are you planning on having? If security matters to you then a SQL db may be the only way to go.

Comment: I think only two....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If security extension doesn't matter you could serialize the values to a file. Json is nice and simple (using json.net). If you need to have more allowances, you could make it an array instead of upper and lower.

Define a class;

```
public class Allowances
    {
        public decimal LowerAllowance { get; set; }
        public decimal UpperAllowance { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can serialize/deserialize that to the file.

```
        var allowances = new Allowances
        {
            LowerAllowance = 10000m,
            UpperAllowance = 45000m
        };

        File.WriteAllText("allowances.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allowances));

        var readAllowances = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Allowances>(File.ReadAllText("allowances.json"));

        Console.WriteLine(readAllowances.LowerAllowance);
        Console.WriteLine(readAllowances.UpperAllowance);
```

You can create a screen in your app that loads the values up, then saves them back.

Comment: Thanks I will look into json and come back mark answered in a bit